# Code Comparison - Which is better in terms of runtime?

Tags: performance, turbo-c++

CODE 1

```
while(fin.eof()==false) {
    fin.read((char*)& Object_2, sizeof(Object_2)); //Reads a record for printing
    class_object.display();

    fin.read((char*)& Object_2, sizeof(Object_2)); //Reads the next record space for eof detection
    if(fin.eof() == true)
        break;  //Break out of the loop on encountering eof
    else
        fin.seekg(-signed(sizeof(Object_1)), ios :: cur);  //File Pointer Correction
}
```

CODE 2

```
while(fin.eof()==false) {
    fin.read((char*)& Object_2, sizeof(Object_2)); //Reads a record for printing
    if(fin.eof() == true)
          break;
    else
          class_object.display();
```

Which one is better in terms of runtime? The CODE1 is not allowing an unnecessary loop step to be executed in the while loop. On the other hand, the CODE2 just breaks when the while loops executes for the last time(unnecessary loop step).

P.S.- I understand that saving up on the last step of the loop barely makes any difference in the runtime, but I'm just curious as to which one is better.

NOTE: I use TurboC++ because of my school.

Comment: If you care about speed you have to measure it.

Comment: Tell your instructor to **STOP USING TurboC++**

Comment: Do `Object_1` and `Object_2` have the same size? is `fin` some type of `std::istream`?

Comment: avoid `fin.eof()==false` and similar things. Use `if (!fin.eof())` and `if (fin.eof())` instead @CharlesBailey there's no std lib in Turbo C++

Comment: And Turbo C++ is very bad at optimization. In modern OSes they have buffering which helps a lot

Comment: The runtime of this code is likely dominated by waiting for I/O to complete. The first version just adds complexity for little or no benefit.

Comment: Assuming std::ifstream (your code looks very much alike): You should always check for `if(fin)` - this catches not only `fin.eof()`, but also `fin.fail()` - if fin.fail() occurs, you are caught in an endless loop as any further read will fail, too, and you'll never reach EOF. However, you'd display *one and the same* (the one of the last successful read) input again and again...

Comment: Maybe you should have a look ad [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). You are trying premature optimisation at probably irrelevant part. What about this: `while(fin.eof()) { read(); if(fin.eof()) { display(); } }` Doesn't that read easier (apart from being shortened...)? Be aware that I did not follow my previous comment deliberately for offering you better comparison only! (Write instead: `while/if(fin)`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your profiler tell you?

On a modern operating system, the faster solution (due to least overhead) would be to map the file in memory and thus avoid the read/seek calls altogether.